# Maximum how many Remote Site settings are registered and how many Remote site settings are active at a time in salesforce organization

Tags: admin

I am trying to create remote site settings for each clients for callout, before going ahead i would like to know about limit of maximum remote sites registered with a salesforce org. Kindly give me governor limit of active remote sites in an salesforce organization.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. It's important, on this site, to show that you've done some research and have tried to resolve the problem or figure out the answer to your question. Questions that don't do this tend to be downvoted and closed pretty quickly.

Comment: That said, I'm not finding any limit specified by Salesforce in a quick search of [the official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/). This generally means that there is no practical limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a limit to how many Remote Site entries you can set. If there were, there'd be a clearly documented limit somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply remote site settings limit is not mentioned in any of salesforce documentation or any of governor limit page